# Skill Listings On career.stackoverflow Jobs Feed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, feed

I am trying to to parse the feed for stackoverflow jobs(http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed) . Though the webpage shows relevant skill tags, but in the RSS feed, the skills don't exist. Is there any alternate way to get the skill set listings there?

It would be very helpful and convenient if stackoverflow team facilitates the skills listing in jobs feed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented this using `<category>` tags in each feed item (job). So if a job had the tags [java](/questions/tagged/java)[spring](/questions/tagged/spring)[jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa)[html](/questions/tagged/html) and [css](/questions/tagged/css), the feed item for that job would look something like this...

```
<item>
<guid isPermaLink="true">http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/36162/web-developer-biddingforgood</guid>
<link>http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/36162/web-developer-biddingforgood</link>
<category>java</category>
<category>spring</category>
<category>jpa</category>
<category>html</category>
<category>css</category>
<title>Web Developer at BiddingForGood, Inc. (Cambridge, MA)</title>
<description>&lt;p&gt;Do you want to make a difference in the world? Do you want to be part of one of the fastest growing tech companies in the Boston area? Do you want to help create a service that gives charities and schools $6 back for every $1 they spend and has raised over $200 million for thousands of worthy causes?&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;p&gt;The BiddingForGood development team is looking for a new Web Developer to help take us to the next level. We provide online auction and other fundraising tools to nonprofits. We're a small, friendly team that focuses on delivering great software to our clients without a lot of process overhead.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;p&gt;Position includes competitive sick/vacation/holiday package, equity, health, dental, long-term disability, life insurance and 401k plan. &amp;nbsp;Sponsorship and/or relocation assistance is not available for this position.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;p&gt;All resumes should be sent to jobs_tech@biddingforgood.com. Please include salary requirements when applying for this position. Email response only. We are an equal opportunity employer.&lt;/p&gt;</description>
<pubDate>Tue, 18 Jun 2013 16:39:16 Z</pubDate>
<a10:updated>2013-06-18T16:39:16Z</a10:updated>
```

Comment: Great Work Jason. I have checked and found it working :D . Thanks a lot.